# Failed assertion: line 118 pos 10: '(displayLarge == null && displayMedium == null && displaySmall == null && headlineMedium == null &&

Tags: flutter

======== Exception caught by widgets library =======================================================
The following assertion was thrown building MyApp(dirty):
Cannot mix 2018 and 2021 terms in call to TextTheme() constructor.
'package:flutter/src/material/text_theme.dart':
Failed assertion: line 118 pos 10: '(displayLarge == null && displayMedium == null && displaySmall == null && headlineMedium == null &&
headlineSmall == null && titleLarge == null && titleMedium == null && titleSmall == null &&
bodyLarge == null && bodyMedium == null && bodySmall == null && labelLarge == null && labelSmall == null) ||
(headline1 == null && headline2 == null && headline3 == null && headline4 == null &&
headline5 == null && headline6 == null && subtitle1 == null && subtitle2 == null &&
bodyText1 == null && bodyText2 == null && caption == null && button == null && overline == null)'

D/EGL_emulation( 6728): app_time_stats: avg=92344.32ms min=92344.32ms max=92344.32ms count=1

Can anyone help what this problem means??

[image]

Comment: Please also paste the code where the problem is happening so it will give more details on how to solve the issue...

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 3):

I guess you tried to instantiate a `TextTheme()` object by specifying all possible constructor arguments. However, if you see the constructor's [documentation](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/TextTheme/TextTheme.html), it (unclearly) specifies that:

> Please note that you can not mix and match the 2018 styles with the 2021 styles. Only one or the other is allowed in this constructor. The 2018 styles will be deprecated and removed eventually.

What is unclear in the documentation is which text style properties are since 2018 (and deprecated) and which are their newer 2021 replacements.

A quick way to avoid mixing deprecated and newer text style options is either use:

1. the ones ending with `Large`/`Medium`/`Small` (e.g. `bodyLarge` or `labelSmall` ...).

or:

2. the rest of the style options (e.g. `bodyText1`, `headline2`, `caption`, `button`, `overline` ...)

A more recommended approach would be to define your application-wide text styling using a ready-made typography style, adding geometry on top of it, like in the below:

```dart
const typeTheme = Typography.whiteMountainView;

TextTheme txtTheme = Typography.whiteMountainView.copyWith(
  bodyText1: typeTheme.bodyText1?.copyWith(fontSize: 16),
  bodyText2: typeTheme.bodyText2?.copyWith(fontSize: 14),
  headline1: typeTheme.headline1?.copyWith(fontSize: 32),
  headline2: typeTheme.headline2?.copyWith(fontSize: 28),
  headline3: typeTheme.headline3?.copyWith(fontSize: 24),
  headline4: typeTheme.headline4?.copyWith(fontSize: 21),
  headline5: typeTheme.headline5?.copyWith(fontSize: 18),
  headline6: typeTheme.headline6?.copyWith(fontSize: 16),
  subtitle1: typeTheme.subtitle1?.copyWith(fontSize: 24),
  subtitle2: typeTheme.subtitle2?.copyWith(fontSize: 21),
);
```